# Not Able to Generate Key For Phonegap getting keytool error

Tags: javascript, cordova, command-line, phonegap-build, android-keystore

Hello Friends I am Trying To generating Keys to use on buil.phonegap.com 
I am using command

```js
keytool -genkey -v -keystore [keystore_name].keystore -alias [alias_name] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

And I got error after completing the whole procedure
Image Link https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm9bf.jpg

So please help me . Or If there any another option to generate key then please tell me

Comment: Did you run the prompt as admin?

Comment: ohh thank you but where the key's are stored?

Comment: It's stored where you run the command...

Answer (score 0):

You have to rund the cli as administrator by right clicking on it. 
then your file will probably be stored in the location that would look like something similar to this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin
```